# Translating cURL request with -G to PHP

Tags: php, facebook, api, curl, webhooks

I'm trying to use the Facebook Marketing API as detailed in [this tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/webhooks/v2.5).

However I'm stumped with how to translate this suggested cURL command line request into it's PHP equivalent:

```
curl -G \
-d 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/<LEAD_ID>
```

I would normally do this:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$access_token);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

But that produces an 'Unsupported post request' error when attempting to run it. I think I am misunderstanding what the '-G' means in the command line version?

Comment: You guessed, it, you don't understand what `-G` means. Find it [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) (or: `man curl` or `curl --help`). Basically, it transforms the request into a `GET`, even if you specify 'post data'.

Comment: @Kenney is right, but that should be an answer, not a comment. Chris, the effect of what Kenney suggests is that you remove: `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);`

Comment: Thanks both, that's set me on the right course to solving this, will mark as resolved if you want to put your response as a question @Kenney

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [man curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-G):

> **-G, --get**
>
> When used, this option will make all data specified with -d, --data, --data-binary or --data-urlencode to be used in an HTTP GET request instead of the POST request that otherwise would be used. The data will be appended to the URL with a '?' separator.

There's no [cURL option flag in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) that directly corresponds to this. You can use

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
```

or

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 'GET');
```

but this is hardly necessary:

> **CURLOPT_HTTPGET**
>
> **TRUE** to reset the HTTP request method to GET. Since GET is the default, this is only necessary if the request method has been changed.

You will have to specify the request parameters differently: instead of setting `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, append them as a query string to the URL (using [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) or the equivalent [curl_escape](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-escape.php) if needed):

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . '?accesstoken='.urlencode('<ACCESS_TOKEN>');
```